# Join multiple table with active storage in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm having problem while joining 2 tables. I'm used to active storage for save file. But I'm join 2 tables it not working. I'm join table bills on products.

Here is Bill model:

```
class Bill < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Here is Product model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :bills
  def new

  end
  def list
  end
end
```

I'm execute table Products with command

```
Product.all
```

and then result

```
[#<Product:0x00007f3d68ee4998
  id: 22,
  created_at: Tue, 25 May 2021 14:16:11.732340000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 25 May 2021 14:16:11.775029000 UTC +00:00,
  name: "Bánh aghahhhahgha",
  des: "fgkagjagaahghahaghhah",
  money: 2000000.0,
  image: nil>]
```

`image` is nil because active storage saved it.

And I'm execute Bill table with command

```
Bill.all
```

Here is result

```
[#<Bill:0x00007f3d68875008
  id: 8,
  user_id: 1,
  status: nil,
  message: nil,
  created_at: Tue, 25 May 2021 14:32:24.182690000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 25 May 2021 14:32:24.182690000 UTC +00:00,
  number_phone: "0328267412",
  quality: 3,
  money: 6000000.0,
  product_id: 22>]
```

And I'm joining 2 tables with command

```
Bill.joins(:product).select('bills.*, products.image a
s image, products.name as name')
```

Result

```
[#<Bill:0x0000556da2ce7ba0
  id: 8,
  user_id: 1,
  status: nil,
  message: nil,
  created_at: Tue, 25 May 2021 14:32:24.182690000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 25 May 2021 14:32:24.182690000 UTC +00:00,
  number_phone: "0328267412",
  quality: 3,
  money: 6000000.0,
  product_id: 22>]
```

Anyone solutions, please help me!
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute

```rb
bill = Bill.joins(:product).select('bills.*, products.image a
s image, products.name as name')
```

*It's actually trying to load data from image column which is in the product table. Active Record don't work that way.
When we write `has_one_attached :image` we are not binding it with product tables `image` column, it's declaring one association with `active_storage_attachments` table.*

---

Here is explanation.

`has_one_attached :image`, which is a relation between `product` table and `active_storage_attachments` table.

When we run `rails active_storage:install` those migration get added into application.

so the actual relation is

```rb
class Bill
  belongs_to :product
end

and

class Product
  has_one :image
end

Note: (`image` for us to access, the real table name is `active_storage_attachments`)
```

Now the query you want is something like this to return image by joining the product.

```rb
=> bill = Bill.joins(:product).joins("INNER JOIN active_storage_attachments on active_storage_attachments.record_id = products.id and active_storage_attachments.record_type = 'Product'").select('bills.*, active_storage_attachments.* as image, products.name as name'))

=> bill.image
#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f911d8a2540
 @name="image",
 @record=
  #<Product:0x00007f911dadf448
   id: 1,
   ...
```

`bill.image` in above example will return the image record and it will look like this. But it won't execute a extra query to load the image so don't worry.

to access the image in frontend

```rb
<%= image_tag url_for(bill.image) %>
```

Here is the full guide of ActiveStorage https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#what-is-active-storage-questionmark

Comment: Hello, I'm tried to access table products, but it isn't in result
https://imgur.com/m5QJjum.png

Comment: @NguyenNguyen We can have the url of image using `url_for(bill.image)` we have to pass the instance of image I mean `ActiveStorage::Attached` into `url_for`.

Result in query will always be an object of the relevant ActiveStorage model, to get the url we have to use that method.

Comment: I'm understood, but I'm want to get all columns of table Products (as name, des,...) with INNER JOIN, but it's not working. We can check out here, below is screen shoot of execute query
https://i.imgur.com/m5QJjum.png
Thank you for helping!

Comment: @NguyenNguyen Actually it's object of Bill not Product so all those value from product table will not be visible on console, BUT it's actually there.
try calling `<your_query>.first.product_name` and it will return the value without executing a different query.